# Android - Determining how hard is touch button pressed

Tags: android, button

Is there a way to determine how hard is button pressed on touch screen?
Maybe using accelerometer details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the pressure by [MotionEvent.getPressure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28int%29)

*Note: pressure i.e. how much pixel covered by your fingure touch.*

**as more number pixel covered the more harder you touched.**

Comment: I'm going to write drums application. So I want to have louder sound when  you hit drum harder. What do you think is that a good point to use method suggested by you in my case?

Comment: Yes, you can have a try with it.